# How to use editor.md inside svelte?

Tags: editor, rollupjs, svelte

I want to include the [editor.md markdown editor](http://editor.md.ipandao.com/en.html) in a svelte component.
I've tried setting it up but I got nothing: not a stack trace from javascript, nor any kind of clue about what the problem should be.

I include the main relevant files for the problem at hand.

`rollup.config.js`:

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'app',
    file: 'public/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
    svelte({
        // enable run-time checks when not in production
        dev: !production,
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file — better for performance
        css: css => {
        css.write('public/bundle.css');
        }
    }),

    // If you have external dependencies installed from
    // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
    // some cases you'll need additional configuration —
    // consult the documentation for details:
    // https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs
    resolve({
        browser: true,
        preferBuiltins: true,
        dedupe: importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/')
    }),
    commonjs(),
    globals({
        dirname: false,
        filename: false,
        baseDir: false
    }),
    builtins(),
    // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
    // browser on changes when not in production
    !production && livereload('public'),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
    clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

`src/App.svelte`:

```
<script>
 import { onMount } from 'svelte';
 import jQuery from 'jquery';
 import editormd from 'editor.md/editormd';

 export let content = "# Edit!";

 onMount(() => {
   window.jQuery = jQuery;
   var editor = editormd("editor", {
       width: "90%",
       height: 640,
       autoLoadModules: false,
   });
 });
</script>

<style>
 @import "editor.md/css/editormd.css";
</style>

<div id="editor">
    <textarea bind:value={content}/>
</div>
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rollup": "^1.12.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-inject": "^3.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "^2.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-globals": "^1.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^4.0.4",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "editor.md": "^1.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "sirv-cli": "^0.4.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "autobuild": "rollup -c -w",
    "dev": "run-p start:dev autobuild",
    "start": "sirv public --single",
    "start:dev": "sirv public --single --dev"
  }
}
```

I would expect the editor to load, but as a result I only get the raw textarea shown.
In the developer console I just get nothing shown.
I'm a newbie with rollup configuration and plugins, so I think I messed up those, but cannot understand what is wrong with them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CommonJS distribution of this library is a factory, so you need to do this:

```js
const factory = editormd();
const editor = factory(id, opts);
```

In the REPL I can get it slightly further along by replacing `id` with a jQuery object: https://svelte.dev/repl/355398c8d6bd4081980ed2abfc5f4286?version=3.9.2

Beyond that, though, it looks like there's a bunch of configuration required to load various resources, and I have no idea how to set it up.

Comment: Thank you a lot, at least I've got some error messages to proceed further.
I think the [example on manually loading modules](https://github.com/pandao/editor.md/blob/master/examples/manually-load-modules.html) is of some interest.
I'll try playing with the repl to see if I get something to work.

Comment: I got it to work by setting (in your code) id="editor" (and not a jQuery object), `opts["path"] = "../lib/"` and copying the directory `node_modules/editor.md/lib/` to svelte `public/lib/`.
This in local development.
I'm now investigating whether it is possible to bundle everything without copying files.